# Deserializing a file

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

Hi I Have a BOOKING class as follows:

```vb
Public Class BOOKING ': Inherits List(Of Message)
    'Private Property MessageProperty As Message

    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property partner As String

    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property transaction As String

    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property version As String

    Public Property [Message] As BookingMessage

    Public Sub New()
        ' create a new Msg object
        [Message] = New BookingMessage
    End Sub
```

And the a message class as follows:

```vb
Public Class BookingMessage


Private MessageTypeProperty As String = ""
Private CustomerNumberProperty As String = ""
Private BookingReferenceProperty As String = ""
Private CustomerBookingReferenceProperty As String = ""

Public Property MessageType As String
    Get
        Return MessageTypeProperty
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        MessageTypeProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property CustomerNumber As String
    Get
        Return CustomerNumberProperty
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        CustomerNumberProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

'Mandatory If MessageType is Either A or D
Public Property BookingReference As String
    Get
        Return BookingReferenceProperty
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        BookingReferenceProperty = value
    End Set
End Property

'Optional
Public Property CustomerBookingReference As String
    Get
        Return CustomerBookingReferenceProperty
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        CustomerBookingReferenceProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I can create and serialize the file using the code below.

```vb
Public Shared Function SaveAsXML(ByRef val As BOOKING)
    Try
        Dim y As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\ftptest\New Booking\4854.xml",
               IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

        Dim x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(BOOKING))
        x.Serialize(y, val)

        y.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

And I've tried to deserialize using this code:

```vb
Try
    Dim Samples As New List(Of BOOKING)
    Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("c:\ftptest\New Booking")
    For Each fl In Files
        'Deserialize XML file
        Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(fl)
        Dim i As New BOOKING
        Dim x As New XmlSerializer(i.GetType)
        i = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
        Samples.Add(i)
     Next
     Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = Samples
     Return True
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try
```

All the properties from booking go into the datagridview,
but where the message properties should go I just have the header message with ftpsample.bookingmessage inside it,

My XML file is as follows.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BOOKING xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" partner="company name" transaction="BOOKING" version="1.0">
  <Message>
   <MessageType>C</MessageType>
   <CustomerNumber>123</CustomerNumber>
   <BookingReference>5845</BookingReference>
   <CustomerBookingReference>036598</CustomerBookingReference>
  </Message>
 </BOOKING>
```

Any help on how to deserialize this would be great thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code that compiles? Your class definitions are not valid.

Comment: Try it now I forgot to put in the private properties.

Comment: refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cca2d5s9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically just the reverse of the code to serialize, but first you should make a change to the serializing part in SaveAsXML:

```
Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\ftptest\New Booking\4854.xml",
       IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

     Dim x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(BOOKING))
     x.Serialize(fs, val)

End Using
```

Generally, if something implementes a Dispose Property, use it and the easiest way is with a `Using` block.  To deserialize:

```
Dim Bb As BOOKING

Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(myFileName, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim y As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(BOOKING))
    Bb = CType(y.Deserialize(fs), BOOKING)
End Using
```

If you are using Option Strict (and you really should be), `Ctype` just converts the return from the serializer from Object to Booking.

Finally, `BookingMessage` properties could be auto implement properties like those in `Booking`.  No real need for all that code in this case.